# How to combine gunzipped fastq files?

Tags: cat, gzip

How can I combine gzipped fastq files?
I tried this for read 1 and read 2

```
zcat file_1.fastq.gz file_2.fastq.gz | gzip > combined.fastq.gz
```

but it is giving me unequal number of reads. Why?
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Try `gzcat` instead of `zcat`. And why is this tagged `awk`?

Comment: @Kevin Tagging Fixed

Comment: Dude... Awesome. Are you working with nucleotide sequences?

Comment: Relevant SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8005155/2808351; one can simply concatenate gzip files and get a proper gzip file, no need to uncompress.

Answer (score 5):

To combine (concatenate) two files, use `cat`:

```
$ cat file1 file2 >file3
```

This also works on files compressed with `gzip`, `bzip2` and `xz` (and possibly others) because of the way that those compression formats are structured.

For example, let's say I have two compressed Fasta files (or any two compressed files that I'd like to concatenate):

```
$ gzcat file1.fa.gz
>seq1
ACTACTACTACTACTACTACTACTACT

$ gzcat file2.fa.gz
>seq1
GATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAAAAAAAA
```

I combine them, without any uncompression or re-compression:

```
$ cat file1.fa.gz file2.fa.gz >file3.fa.gz
```

The result is a combined and compressed file:

```
$ gzcat file3.fa.gz
>seq1
ACTACTACTACTACTACTACTACTACT
>seq1
GATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAAAAAAAA
```

---

Note that if this gives you data that is somehow wrong, then the error is likely also present in one (or both) of your original files.

Comment: If the files are large, say you want to save some time. will cat f1.gz >> f2.gz work.  mv f2.gz f1_plus_f2.gz.  I want to remove the original files to save some space.

Comment: @KeminZhou Yes, but only if your intention is to combine the contents of the two files. You would not be able to automatically separate the combined files into two files again.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`tar -cvzf fastq.tar.gz /path/to/all/fastqs/*.gz`

Or are you trying to skip the tar?

Comment: There's no `tar` in the filenames.

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't matter The end result is the first operand, meaning a file named `fastq.tar.gz` will be created that contains all fastq files that end in .gz in path `/path/to/fastqs/`  I was asking if he was not wanting to use tar...

Comment: I see, I evidently didn't read the options (`-c` at least). Regardless, it looks like he wants to concatenate the contents of the files, not tar them up.

Answer (score 0):

**Do this instead:**

```
#!/bin/bash
gzip -d $1 && gzip -d $2
1A=`sed 's/.gz//g`
2A=`sed 's/.gz//g`
cat $2A >> $1A
gzip -c $1A > $1A.gz
```

**Invocation:**

```
$> bash yourNewScriptIMadeForYou file1.gz file2.gz
```

**Explanation**

- Line 1 Declares Environment as Bash.
- Line 2 Invokes GZIP [-d] to extract archive, "&&" operator means "DO THIS and THEN DO THAT if THIS WORKED."
- Line 3-4: Stream text processing to strip ".gz" post-fix from inputs $1 and $2.
- Line 5: Concatenate the contents of $2A to the end of the body of $1A
- Line 6: Create a new GZIP file named the same as the first file input, or if you wanted to include both names...

  gzip -c $1A > $1A$2A.gz

**If you show me your directory structure, and describe how you need to combine fastq files, I can create a better script that is perfectly fit to your requirement.**