# How to concatenate only identical file names within two folders to one file?

Tags: cat

I have fasta.qz sequence files with identical names, but in two different folders that I need to concatenate (concatenate always those two with identical names only!).
The directory structure looks like this:

*sequences*

```
**|--folderA**

|  \-- \--MOSA_F_TAC01n.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC08n.rem.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --WAIN_N_15m.rem.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC01n.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC08n.rem.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --WAIN_N_16m.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC01n.rem.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --PAUA_F_16v.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --WAIN_N_16m.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC01n.rem.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --PAUA_F_16v.2.fq.gz     


**| \--folderB**       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC01n.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC08n.rem.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --WAIN_N_15m.rem.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC01n.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC08n.rem.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --WAIN_N_16m.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC01n.rem.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --PAUA_F_16v.1.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --WAIN_N_16m.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --MOSA_F_TAC01n.rem.2.fq.gz       
 |  \-- --PAUA_F_16v.2.fq.gz
```

As you see, the file names are identical (their content is not, i.e., it is complementary thus need to `cat`). I would like to keep the files' names and concatenate the identical files into one single file with said name (in e.g. a new folder named folderC).

Comment: You could probably loop over the files in one directory and check if a file of each name exists in the other directory.  If so, cat the two of them into a new file in the third directory.

Comment: Are all files in dirA guaranteed to have a pair in dirB ? If not, what would you want to do with the unpairable ones: skip them or copy them to dirC ?

Comment: all those names actually begin with ```-- ``` or is that filler for your example material? if so, what named them? globbing that on ```eval set --*``` would drop three chars *(the same count in ```../``` incidentally)* for each name, and most standard utility command lines would effect similar drops...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for FILE in dir1/* ; do
    FILE2=dir2/${FILE#*/}
    if [ -f $FILE2 ] ; then
        cat $FILE $FILE2 > dir3/${FILE#*/}
    fi
done
```

Where `dir1` is one of the source directories, `dir2` is the other source directory, and `dir3` is the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid its not that easy. The files' "extensions" indicate those are `gzip`ped data that need to be `gunzip`ped before they can be concatenated. Stealing from Christian Gibbons' answer, try

```
for FILE in dir1/* ; do
    FILE2=dir2/${FILE#*/}
    if [ -f $FILE2 ] ; then
        gunzip -c $FILE $FILE2 | gzip > dir3/${FILE#*/}
    fi
done
```

Comment: [How to combine gunzipped fastq files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158941/22142)

Comment: OK, admitted they can be `cat`ted, but `man gzip`:
       `If you want to recompress concatenated files to get better compression, do:             gzip -cd old.gz | gzip > new.gz`