# Need to iterate through subdirectories, concatenating files, with an iterative number

Tags: shell, cat, for

I'm trying to concatenate files from three different subdirectories into one file. The names of the files in each subdirectory are exactly the same. I'd like to use a loop to iterate through the subdirectories, and then place an iteration number into the newly named concatenated file, in a new directory. 
For example a directory structure like:

```
Foo
|||
||Bar3
|Bar2
Bar1
```

Inside each Bar(?) folder are files named:
File1, File2, File3

I'd like to concatenate the Files with the same names to a larger file with a new name including a number:

```
cat Foo/Bar1/File1 Foo/Bar2/File1 Foo/Bar3/File1 > /combined_files/all_file1

cat Foo/Bar1/File2 Foo/Bar2/File2 Foo/Bar3/File2 > /combined_files/all_file2

cat Foo/Bar1/File3 Foo/Bar2/File3 Foo/Bar3/File3 > /combined_files/all_file3
```

From the `Foo` directory I can use:

```
for number in {1..3}
    do
    cat Bar1/File$number\_* Bar2/File$number\_* Bar3/File$number\_* > combined_files/'all_files'$number
    done
exit
```

But I need to have a more universal script, for larger numbers of Bar directories, and Files. 
I want something like

```
files=`ls ./Run1/ | wc -l`   #to count the number of files and assign a number
For n in {1..$files}
    do
    cat Bar1/File$n\_* Bar2/File$n\_* Bar3/File$n\_* > combined_files/'all_files'$n
    done
```

But I'm stuck.

Comment: Yes I want all the files in BarX, but no X will go from 1 to a large number.

Comment: Does order need to be preserved between each run? Eg should `Bar1/File2` always appear in the concatenated output before `Bar2/File1`? This will affect whether it can be accomplished using a simple one-liner, or whether a more complicated (perhaps recursive) result will be required.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The files are ordered so the concatenation needs to be ordered.

Comment: This is similar to a question asked a few months ago, but the answers didn't seem to work for me, or maybe I don't interpret them correctly

Comment: Okay, actually the answers here were very close to what I need. Can the code be expanded to larger sets of directories? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465364/how-to-concatenate-only-identical-file-names-within-two-folders-to-one-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

for pathname in Foo/Bar1/File*; do
    filename=${pathname##*/}
    cat "$pathname" \
        "Foo/Bar2/$filename" \
        "Foo/Bar3/$filename" >"combined/all_$filename"
done
```

This would loop over all files whose names matches `File*` under `Foo/Bar1` (we assume that the pattern matches exactly the names we are actually interested in).

For each such file, we extract the filename portion of the pathname, yielding `$filename` (this could also have been done with `filename=$(basename "$pathname")`).  We then concatenate the original file with the corresponding files in the `Foo/Bar2` and `Foo/Bar3` directories, writing the result to a new `all_$filename` file in some other directory.

---

With a bit of error checking:

```
#!/bin/sh

for pathname in Foo/Bar1/File*; do
    if [ ! -f "$pathname" ]; then
        printf '% is not a regular file, skipping\n' "$pathname" >&2
        continue
    fi

    filename=${pathname##*/}

    if [ -f "Foo/Bar2/$filename" ] &&
       [ -f "Foo/Bar3/$filename" ]
    then
        cat "$pathname" \
            "Foo/Bar2/$filename" \
            "Foo/Bar3/$filename" >"combined/all_$filename"
    else
        printf 'Missing %s or %s\n' "Foo/Bar2/$filename" "Foo/Bar3/$filename" >&2
    fi
done
```

---

A variation that also allows for a varied number of `BarN` subdirectories.  It is *assumed* that each `BarN` directory is numbered sequentially from 1 to some large number.

```
#!/bin/sh

# This is just used to count the number of BarN subdirectories.
# The number of these will be $#.
set -- Foo/Bar*/

for pathname in Foo/Bar1/File*; do
    filename=${pathname##*/}

    n=1
    while [ "$n" -le "$#" ]; do
        if [ ! -f "Foo/Bar$n/$filename" ]; then
            printf '%s missing, %s will be incomplete\n' \
                "Foo/Bar$n/$filename" "combined/all_$filename" >&2
            break
        fi

        cat "Foo/Bar$n/$filename"
        n=$(( n + 1 ))
    done >"combined/all_$filename"
done
```

Comment: Just to make shorter, in your last code what if write `cat "Foo/Bar1/$filename" >"combined/all_$filename"` above `n=1` and then make `n=2` instead of 1. So it will save one comparison.

Comment: @Debian_yadav Or just remove the first if statement (which I just did because it looks nicer). In either case, the timing difference will be minuscule.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda very much for the great explanation and code. My directory structure is not as perfect as I described. The BarX directories will be sequentially numbered, but the Filenames can vary from my original post. Using `File*` doesn't always capture the filename correctly. Would it be possible to use something from the other post, like: `${FILE#*/}` to capture the entire filename? I will take the code you have written and work with it tonight. Thank-you.

Comment: @hoytpr If you want to match _all_ files in `Bar1` (that are not hidden filenames), just use `Foo/Bar1/*` instead of `Foo/Bar1/File*`, or construct some other pattern that will match the names that you are interested in.

Comment: @Kusalananda; yes, that's what I should have been doing, but was overthinking when it was the directory structure using `Foo/BarX/Filex` when I should have been using just `BarX/Filex` or as you say; `BarX/*` when running the script from inside the `Foo` directory.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again @Kusalananda and @Debian_yadav. I was able to make your script work on my system. My actual directory names are now:

`Joes
 ||| 
 ||Run3
 |Run2
 Run1`

Inside each RunX directory I created Files named the same but with different contents

Run1\File1
Run2\File1
Run3\File1

First I ran the simple script you showed, slightly modified to my directory structure:

**ANSWER**

```
#!/bin/bash
for pathname in Run1/File*; do
    filename=${pathname##*/}
    cat "$pathname" \
        "Run2/$filename" \
        "Run3/$filename" > "RunCat/all_$filename"
one
```

The script output was a file "allFile1" with contents:
`123`

Your longer (final) script (I named K2script.sh) also worked on my system.
The output exactly the same again after slightly modifying the directory structure:

**ANSWER**

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is just used to count the number of RunN subdirectories.
# The number of these will be $#.
set -- Joes/Run*/

for pathname in Run1/File*; do
    filename=${pathname##*/}

    n=1
    while [ "$n" -le "$#" ]; do
        if [ ! -f "Run$n/$filename" ]; then
            printf '%s missing, %s will be incomplete\n' \
                "Run$n/$filename" "RunCat/all_$filename" >&2
            break
        fi

        cat "Run$n/$filename"
        n=$(( n + 1 ))
    done >"RunCat/all_$filename"
done
```

Also, using the script from
[an other stackexchange discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465364/how-to-concatenate-only-identical-file-names-within-two-folders-to-one-file?rq=1)

**ANSWER**
Changing the folder names made it work on my system.

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in Run1/* ; do
    FILE2=Run2/${FILE#*/}
    FILE3=Run3/${FILE#*/}
    if [ -f $FILE2 ] ; then
        cat $FILE $FILE2 $FILE3 > RunCat/${FILE#*/}
    fi
done
```

I've learned a lot about `while [ "$n" -le "$#" ]; do` and how `${pathname##*/}` works,
but wasn't able to fully grasp why `${FILE#*/}` worked when other wildcard symbols or regular expressions would not.